# How to display values of multiple tables in label?

Tags: mysql

I have four tables each of them have 2 columns. Each table has 1 column with the same name. I want to display the value of each tables column with the same name to their respective labels. How should i query it?

Comment: Use „AS“ to relabel the display name

Comment: @neuhaus That could be an answer :-)

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, I‘m not sure if that‘s what‘s being asked

Comment: The question sounds like the author never read something about SQL queries.